# Create a model class field containing a list of objects from another table in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning `C#` and `ASP.NET MVC Framework` from 2 weeks and I would like to apply these knowledges through a small web application. I need your help/advices in order to set a new field between 2 classes.

**Objective:**

This application should be useful for my soccer team. I have a first CRUD which let to handle players. I can create players, edit players ...

I have a second CRUD which let to handle match details (datetime, pitch, match format ...).

I would like to be able to add available players for a specific match. That is to say, to be able to add a list of players from table `Joueur` inside a field in the table `Match`. Through this way, when I look a match in details, I cna see the list of players in order to create the team composition later with JavaScript if it's possible by moving object on a dynamic picture (not my issue for the moment).

**My class `Joueur`:**

Very simple:

```
namespace FCSL.Models.Joueur
{
    public class Joueur
    {
        [Key, Display(Name = "ID")]
        public int JoueurID { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Nom"), StringLength(30)]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Prénom"), StringLength(30)]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Poste")]

        public string Poste { get; set; }

        public string Image { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I have behind the CRUD generated by Visual Studio which works fine.

**My class `Match`:**

```
namespace FCSL.Models.Match
{
    public class Match
    {
        [Key]
        public int EquipeID { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Date du match")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime MatchDay { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Heure du match")]
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:H:mm}")]
        public DateTime MatchTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Adversaire { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Type de match")]
        public string Format { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Terrain { get; set; }

        [Display]
        public string Tresse { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Mot-clé")]
        public string Slug { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Add a new field:**

Now I would like a new field in my `Match` class in order to select list of players from `Joueur` class in a field named `ListeJoueurs`.

Do I have to add this something like this ?

```
[Required, Display(Name = "Joueurs")]
public List<Joueur.Joueur> ListeJoueurs { get; set; }
```

Then, how I can display a multiple selected dropdown to display this field in my create.cshtml view file ?

Thank you very much by advance

Answer (score 0):

public class Match
{
all old propertiese
publis string ListeJoueurs { get; set; }
}

ViewBag.lstCourse=your list;

```
        @Html.DropDownListFOR(m=>m.ListeJoueurs ,ViewBag.lstCourse as selectectlsist),select"",new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two properties `TeamOne` and `TeamTwo` and in each team add property `Players` as collection that hold the selected players for each team.

In your Class `Match`:

```
namespace FCSL.Models.Match
{
    public class Match
    {
        ...

        public Team TeamOne { get; set; }
        public Team TeamTwo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Add a new class `Team`:

```
namespace FCSL.Models.Match
{
    public class Team
    {
        ...

        [Required, Display(Name = "Joueurs")]
        public List<Joueur.Joueur> ListeJoueurs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You need also to create a view model instead of sending the model to the view, in your viewmodel you need also to transform your `ListJoueurs` into `MultiSelectList`

And you pass your created `viewmodel` throw a `viewbag` like below:

```
public ActionResult Match()
{
    ...
    var match = new MVCApp.Models.Match
    {
        AdversaryTeam = "Equipe de France",
        Field = "Stade de France",
        MatchDay = DateTime.Today,
        MatchTime = DateTime.Now,
        TeamOne = new Team
        {
            Players = new List<Player>
            {
                new Player { PlayerID = 1, Firstname = "Zineeddine", Lastname = "Zidane", Poste = "" },
                new Player { PlayerID = 2, Firstname = "Roberto", Lastname = "Carlos", Poste = "" },
                new Player { PlayerID = 3, Firstname = "Gianluca", Lastname = "Pagliuca", Poste = "" },
            }
        },

         TeamTwo = new Team
         {
            Players = new List<Player>
            {
                new Player { PlayerID = 1, Firstname = "Zineeddine", Lastname = "Zidane", Poste = "" },
                new Player { PlayerID = 2, Firstname = "Roberto", Lastname = "Carlos", Poste = "" },
                new Player { PlayerID = 3, Firstname = "Gianluca", Lastname = "Pagliuca", Poste = "" },
            }
         }
    };

    var vm = new MatchPlayersVM
    {
        Match = match, 
        TeamOnePlayers = match.TeamOne.Players.Select(p => new SelectListItem { Text = p.Firstname, Value = p.PlayerID.ToString() }),
        TeamTwoPlayers = match.TeamTwo.Players.Select(p => new SelectListItem { Text = p.Firstname, Value = p.PlayerID.ToString() }),
    };

    ViewBag.MatchVM = vm;

    return View();
}
```

Finally in your create.chtml add your dropdown like below:

```
@using MVCApp.Models

@model MatchPlayersVM

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TeamOneSelectedValues, ViewBag.MatchVM.TeamOnePlayers as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { multiple = "multiple" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TeamTwoSelectedValues, ViewBag.MatchVM.TeamOnePlayers as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { multiple = "multiple" })
```

Comment: If I understand, I have my models : `Joueur`, `Match`, `Team` an one more in viewmodel (`MatchPlayerVM`) ? But Team and MatchPlayerVM are equivalent no ?

Comment: No, Team is a model that hold the collection of players and other informations. The MathPlayerVM is a ViewModel that represent your data in other format, if you compare them, your model it contains a brut data (your list of players) and your ViewModel contains a transformed list of players.

Comment: You may have 100 properties with many navigations and the benifit of using VM it to gain in performance, to avoid serialization issues and to transform data. You also have one model but you can have multiplie representation of it.